# Having trouble running update through terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

After typing `sudo apt-get update` which I've done quite a bit in the past few months, (I am a new Linux user and kind of went in head first to try to teach myself) the two different error messages I'm getting is as follows:

```
N: Ignoring file 'sp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Error message number two after trying to update through terminal (I believe i also tried the command `sudo apt-get clean` and can't remember why):

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:3 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:4 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 InRelease
Get:5 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:6 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:7 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 Release
Fetched 94.5 kB in 1s (73.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'sp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
W: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key E5220FB7014D0FBDA50DFC2BE5E86C008AA65D56 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first output is saying that some other program is running as `root`. This can happen even if you are using two terminal instances with `sudo`, which happens to me a lot when I'm doing too much at once :D

Also perhaps Geany, Gedit, or some other text editor is using `sudo` or `gksu` to make changes to a low level folder... Are you editing a file or script in your /bin, or something like that?

Another big one is if you are using a GUI package manager (Ubuntu's, Synaptic, etc) which "locks" the admin directory, as in, "someone is already being root right now and there can be only one!"

The second output is explicitly saying that there is a file called "sp" which has no file extension (.txt, .conf, .d, .py, so on). Go into that folder and have a look at that file. Maybe
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sp` to here so we can check it out, too.

Comment: So i followed that extension and it looks like it is a file that just has the text "sudo apt-get update"? considered deleting it, it just a file and is next to a few random xenial files and a text file for PPSSPP  (PSP emulator). and as far as i can see, all i have running right now is one terminal and firefox

Comment: I can't imagine why that would be in there unless you mistakenly created that file? I just created a file called sp in that directory and got the same error. It is essentially just trying to read from that as a ppa or software source... You can safely delete it.

Comment: You could have possibly (maybe) used an in-terminal editor like nano, vim, etc, and had it running when you tried to send the `sudo apt-get update` command. That's all I can think of off the top! The files in there would have the extension **.list**.

Answer (score 0):

First error just means that another apt or dpkg process is running, it runs automaticaly on a schedule to check for updates. Just try again after a few minutes.

As for the second error, the N: line is a file which shouldn´t be there, it was probably put there by accident, you can safely delete it, and avoid running applications as root. :)

The W: line is just a warning, and can´t be fixed by you (well, you can disable epson´s apt source, but then you would not be able to update your printer driver using apt anymore).